# python regex, check last two characters of variable

Tags: python, regex

For a school project I need to write a Python script that validates a Dutch postal code and does this by using regular expressions.

I came up with the following script, two of my regular expressions don't work, I've been stuck on this for a while now and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Below is the script:

```
check1=0
check2=0
check3=0
invoer = input ("Fill in a postal code")
if re.match("^[0-9]{0,4}", invoer):
    check1 = 1
#Below if statement doesn't work (Should checks that the last 2 charcters are capitals)
if re.match("[A-Z]{2}$", invoer):
    check2 = 1
    print ("check 2 works")
#Below if statement doesn't work (Should checks for existence of a space on position 5.)
if re.match("\\s{5}", invoer):
    check3 = 1
    print ("check 3 works")
if re.match("^[A-Z0-9]{0,6}", invoer):
    check3 = 1
    print ("ding1")
if check1 == 1 and check2 == 1 and check3 == 1:
    print ("Postcode is valide")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) looks for a match from the beginning of a string:

> If zero or more characters *at the beginning of string* match the
>   regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject
>   instance. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note
>   that this is different from a zero-length match.

You need to use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead:

```
if re.search("[A-Z]{2}$", invoer):
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks that solves half my problem, now I just need to figure out how to check that the character on position 5 is a space.

Comment: @gijs007 how about something as simple as `invoer[4] == " "`? Well, we might talk about having a single regexp replacing all of the checks but that's probably out of scope here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"\s{5}" matches 5 spaces. You want to match 4 characters then a single space right? Also I use "raw" strings so that I don't have to escape out \'s.  That is r".{4}\s".